# Using TEG to generate electricity for cooling car interior parked in sun

Tags: voltage, automotive, generator, peltier, cooling

I am working on how can I cool down or normalise interior temperature of cars parked in sun for too long as they get real hot. So I thought if this could be done by thermoelectric generators. I don't know if this would work or what would be the problems that would occur but I will explain my design intention of the project.

I would stack some thermoelectric generators and the cool side will be isolated in styrofoam at normal temperature and the hot side will get hot through the sunrays entering the car through window on dashboard. The voltage I would generate I expect is 12 volts, 6 volts of which will go in a single thermoelectric cooler whose hot side will be isolated in styrofoam and as the cool side gets cooler a 6 volts DC fan will start and circulate cool air inside the car from the cool side. I don't know if this would work or not.

Comment: The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore the comments below the question have been moved to chat and the discussion should be continued there (link below). --- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments on the question may be deleted without notice. **Keep the discussion in chat from now on, please!** New answers and edits can still be written, as usual.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130500/discussion-on-question-by-sarthak-tyagi-using-teg-to-generate-electricity-for-co).

Comment: The thing you're looking for already "sorta" exists.   There are tons of solar powered FANS that mount in your car window.  That's an actual practical way to get the inside of your car cooled down.  Or at least "cooler".    i.e.    https://www.amazon.com/Powered-Ventilator-Radiator-Eliminate-Peculiar/dp/B07P24ZMB8

Answer (score 4):

#### No, you can't create power with heat and use the power to remove heat.

You cannot create power with heat and then use that power to run a second similar device that gets rid of the heat.

This is basic Second Law of Thermodynamics stuff - as energy is transformed, it gets wasted because processes are not 100% efficient, and we can't get back to the starting point without adding more energy.

In this case, even at 100% efficiency, the best you could do would be to move the heat into electricity and then absorb the heat using that electricity through cooling.  In practice, even if this were feasible (it isn't) I think you will find it difficult to generate the temperature differences you are looking for; you need a cold side, and everywhere  in the car will likely be just as hot.  Styrofoam doesn't provide a cold side at all, it provides insulation.  Eventually an insulated device would have the same temperature throughout and cease making power.

It is conceivable that if the TEGs had sufficient efficiency that you could generate electricity to run a refrigerant cycle.  A refrigerant cycle can move more heat than the energy you put into it.  But the reality is that the power required to cool a car in the sun is enormous, and a set of TEGs isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Actually since you want to remove heat from the hot side, you CAN do that. But you can also do it by opening a window! And the asker's design has many problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems:

> I would stack some thermoelectric generators and the cool side will be isolated in styrofoam at normal temperature

This won't work. The cool side gets hot. When the cool side and the hot side are the same temperature you don't generate any power any more. You have to keep the cool side cool, for example by putting it outside the car. Thermodynamics is a PITA.

> and the hot side will get hot through the sunrays entering the car through window on dashboard.

Fair enough for the hot side.

Note: just in case it wasn't obvious, you won't *just* have the Peltier module by itself. You'll probably have some blocks of metal and possibly fans to move the heat around. For example, to heat up the hot side you can attach it to a block of black-painted metal on the dashboard. Metal moves heat well, and black absorbs light well and heats up.

> 12 volts, 6 volts of which will go

voltage is not like that, but you will learn this when you study electronics and it's not important for now.

> will go in a single thermoelectric cooler whose hot side will be isolated in styrofoam

You have the same problem as the generator, but in reverse. As the cold side gets cold the hot side gets hot. If the hot side is too hot, the cool side also gets hot because the heat leaks back through the cooler, and if the hot side is way too hot, the cooler breaks and you have to buy a new one. So you have to keep the hot side cool, for example by putting it outside the car.